# Android : ListView get jumbled up while trying to write ViewHolder class for ListView with Section Headers

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, sectionheader

I am using a ListView with sections and section headers. Below is the GetView method of adapter without ViewHolder class, which works fine but when scrolled several times, freezes the UI and also kills the app on several devices.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    //View v = convertView;// = convertView;

    //System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView);
    final Item i = items.get(position);
    if (i != null) 
        {
            if(i.isSection())
                {
                    SectionItem si = (SectionItem)i;

                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, null);

                    v.setOnClickListener(null);
                    v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
                    v.setLongClickable(false);

                    final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
                    sectionView.setTypeface(StaticUtils.sTypeFace(context));
                    sectionView.setText(si.getTitle());
                    v.setEnabled(false);
                }
            else
                {
                    EntryItem ei = (EntryItem)i;
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_entry, null);

                    final TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title);
                    final ImageView mImg = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_drawable);
                    mImg.getLayoutParams().height = mIvPrams;
                    mImg.getLayoutParams().width = mIvPrams;
                    title.setTypeface(StaticUtils.sTypeFace(context));
                    title.setSelected(true);
                    if (title != null) 
                        title.setText(ei.title);
                    imageLoader.displayImage(ei.imgUrl, mImg, options, animateFirstListener);
                }       
        }
    return v;
}
```

Now, I tried to implement ViewHolder class to it to improve the freeze issue. Below is the code with ViewHolder class that I implemented for the adapter. However, when I scroll with below implementation, the ListView gets all jumbled up. It is not able to hold the index of its elements. If I try to do changes, I also get NullPointerException at times when I scroll back from bottom to top.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    //View v = null;// = convertView;

    //System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView);
    final Item i = items.get(position);
    if (i != null) 
        {
            if(i.isSection())
                {
                    /*if (convertView == null) {
                        v = (View) vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, null);
                        // Do some initialization
                    } else {
                        v = convertView;
                    }*/

                    if(v==null)
                        {
                            mHolder = new ViewHolder();
                            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, null);
                            mHolder.s = (SectionItem)i;
                            mHolder.mSectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
                            v.setTag(mHolder);
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            mHolder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();
                            //v = convertView;
                        }

                    v.setOnClickListener(null);
                    v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
                    v.setLongClickable(false);

                    //final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
                    mHolder.mSectionView.setTypeface(StaticUtils.sTypeFace(context));
                    mHolder.mSectionView.setText(mHolder.s.getTitle());
                    v.setEnabled(false);
                }
            else
                {

                    //v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_entry, null);
                    if (v == null) {

                            mHolder = new ViewHolder();
                        v = (View) vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_entry, null);
                        mHolder.e = (EntryItem)i;
                        mHolder.mTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title);
                        mHolder.mImg = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_drawable);
                        mHolder.mImg.getLayoutParams().height = mIvPrams;
                        mHolder.mImg.getLayoutParams().width = mIvPrams;
                        v.setTag(mHolder);
                        // Do some initialization
                    } else {
                        mHolder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();
                    }

                    //mHolder.mTitle.setTypeface(StaticUtils.sTypeFace(context));
                    //mHolder.mTitle.setSelected(true);
                    if (mHolder.mTitle != null) 
                        mHolder.mTitle.setText(mHolder.e.title);
                    imageLoader.displayImage(mHolder.e.imgUrl, mHolder.mImg, options, animateFirstListener);
                }       
        }
    return v;
}


public class ViewHolder
{
    TextView mSectionView, mTitle;
    ImageView mImg;
    EntryItem e;
    SectionItem s;
}
```

I hope to get a solution on how can I improve my code and write a proper ViewHolder class for this adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the `NullPointerExceptions` because you're inflating two types of views and when you scroll Android will reuse your views but at some point it will bring you `R.layout.list_item_entry` for `isSection()` evaluated to true or vice-versa: `R.layout.list_item_section` for `isSection()` evaluated to false.

What you need to do is to implement two other methods in your adapter: 
 - [`getViewTypeCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) this needs to return the number of view types you're inflating. In your case you need to return 2.
 - [`getItemViewType(int position)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) - based in the position, you need to return either 0, either 1.

Now, in your adapter detect first what is the item view type by calling `getItemViewType` and then apply your current logic.

**EDIT** With a blind coding based on above the `getView` method would look something like below (I didn't check how compilable this would be, but I am sure you would understand what I meant):

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Item i = items.get(position);
    if(i.isSection()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Item i = items.get(position);
    int itemViewType = getItemViewType(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (itemViewType == 0) {
        if (v == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, null);
            viewHolder.mSectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
            v.setTag(mHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        v.setOnClickListener(null);
        v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
        v.setLongClickable(false);

        //final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
        viewHolder.mSectionView.setTypeface(StaticUtils.sTypeFace(context));
        viewHolder.mSectionView.setText(mHolder.s.getTitle());
        v.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        EntryItem e = (EntryItem) i;
        //v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_entry, null);
        if (v == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            v = (View) vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_entry, null);
            viewHolder.mTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title);
            viewHolder.mImg = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_drawable);
            viewHolder.mImg.getLayoutParams().height = mIvPrams;
            viewHolder.mImg.getLayoutParams().width = mIvPrams;
            v.setTag(mHolder);
            // Do some initialization
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        //mHolder.mTitle.setTypeface(StaticUtils.sTypeFace(context));
        //mHolder.mTitle.setSelected(true);
        if (viewHolder.mTitle != null)
            viewHolder.mTitle.setText(mHolder.e.title);
        imageLoader.displayImage(e.imgUrl, viewHolder.mImg, options, animateFirstListener);
    }
    return v;
}
```

An observation: don't keep the data model class in the Holder class since the holder will be reused in other similar views in a different position and there the data model class that you keep in Holder will not be valid for that position. You have already the `getItem(position)` method available. Use that instead!

Comment: Can you show me some example with it? I am able to understand this but  it will be more clear if there was an example with it.

Comment: You need clarifications in the `getView` method I suppose, right?

Comment: Life saver! Thanks man. Still I will check it for different devices and see if this is working smooth. Accepting your solution.

Comment: I have modified my code based on this Answer but still I am getting the jumbled list when scrolling